# Laravel Storage File not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-storage

I am trying to bind a downloadable csv template to a button which will sit in storage but i keep receiving an error i have tried below but having no luck can anyone see where i am going wrong?

**Download Route**

Created a download route which refers to the template in storage.

```
public function download()
{
   return Storage::download('template.csv');
}
```

**route file**

```
Route::get('invites/download', 'InviteController@download')->name('invite.download');
```

**Button**

```
<a href="{{action('InviteController@download')}}" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Download template</a>
```

**Template location**

```
storage/app/public/template.csv
```

**Error**

This is the error i keep receiving.

```
League \ Flysystem \ FileNotFoundException
File not found at path: template.csv
```

Can i get some help to see where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the issue by simply using `file_get_contents()` instead :

```
return file_get_contents(public_path('storage/template.csv'));
```

This will work if you have created the symlink as well `php artisan storage:link`,

If you want to use `storage_path`, then :

```
return file_get_contents(storage_path('app/public/'.'template.csv'));
```